# unable to get URL data By using activatedRoute.params.subscribe( data: params => { data:{ } })

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

[image: Routing File component that sets the :name(parametercomponent that subscribe the activedroute param) in URL]

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.activeRoute.params.subscribe(( data:Params ) => {
      if(data['name']) this.recipe = this.recipeService.getRecipes().filter( ele => ele.name === data['name'] )[0];
      console.log(' ---- recipe ---- ', this.recipe);
    })
  }
```

I am getting emoty object in data {}, and subscription doesnot fires when there is a change in URL

Comment: you are not passing params to the recipies component path, that is why it is coming empty

Comment: Hi, what do you mean under "data" in your URL? What exactly do you want to get?

Comment: recipeSelected (recipeEle: Recipe):void {
    // console.log('----recipeEle----', recipeEle);
    // this.recipeService.recipeSelectEvent.emit(recipeEle);
    this.router.navigate(['/recipes',recipeEle.name],{'relativeTo':this.activeRoute});
  } /* I am adding Name in the path params and I have subscribed the activatedRoute.params, But I am not getting the name in the subscribed data*/